# Runtime error '91' with using "set" in For Loop

Tags: vba, excel, com

```
Dim Srv As Object                                       
Dim Mdl As Object 

Dim SubVarGroups As Object
Dim SubVarGroup As Object

Dim nSubVarGroup As Integer                            
Dim nSubVar As Integer  

Dim FileName As String  

Set Srv = CreateObject("Simpack.Gui.90900") 
Set Mdl = Srv.Spck.openModel(FileName)  

Set SubVarGroups = Mdl.getSubvarGroupList(False)
nSubVarGroup = SubVarGroups.Count

Dim c As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = 0 To nSubVarGroup

Set SubVarGroup = SubVarGroups.Item(i)
Worksheets("Test").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = SubVarGroup.FullName

Next i
```

I used this code to get some information from the 3rd part program via COM interface. But I got "Run-time error" for the below section

```
Worksheets("Test").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = SubVarGroup.FullName
```

**Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set**

Could you help me where I'm wrong?

Comment: You don't assign a value to the `Filename` variable before you use it at `Set Mdl = Srv.Spck.openModel(FileName)`

Comment: It looks like your for loop would look out of range. Does it help if you change to nsubvargroup to nsubvargroup-1?

Comment: @JeremyKahan you're awesome my friend. : )

Comment: @Hakan - would you agree that this error only occurs on the last iteration of the loop?

Comment: use an intermediate variable in the assignment `dim aaa as variant` ... `aaa = SubVarGroup.FullName` ... `Worksheets("Test").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = aaa`, it should reveal the culrit. and you can examine the value of aaa

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 0 To nSubVarGroup
```

needs to be

```
For i = 0 To (nSubVarGroup-1)
```

because there are only nSubVarGroup items to loop through and the input list is 0-based.
  I cannot prove it without running the code, but I think what happened is that in the last run through the loop as it was, SubVarGroup got assigned to nothing or null ("not set"), so SubVarGroup.FullName choked.